# Converting myClass.ChatColor objects to and from .json files result in undesired leading `Â` characters

Tags: java, json, gson, minecraft, bukkit

I'm storing ChatColor objects stored in a class object. After successfully converting them to json using the Gson api, I want to be able to instantiate ChatColor objects in memory from this stored json file.

Using the code below, I get ChatColor objects who's toString methods return `Â§6`. *they should be returning the same but minus the leading `Â` character*

To make this question easier to read I've reduced the examples down to a single ChatColor object per Theme object.

**Theme.java**

```java
package core.data.objects;

import java.util.Map;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

public class Theme {

    private ChatColor primary, secondary, tertiary, clear, faded, succeed, fail;

    public Theme(Map<String, ChatColor> thisMap) {
        this.primary = thisMap.get("primary");
    }

    public ChatColor getPrimary() { return primary; }

    public void setPrimary(ChatColor primary) { this.primary = primary; }
}
```

ThemeManager.java

```java
package core.data;

import core.data.objects.Theme;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

public class ThemeManager {
    public static Theme currentTheme;

    public static void load() throws IOException {
        try {
            currentTheme = getThemeFromJSON(FileManager.defaultThemeFile);

            System.out.println(ChatColor.GOLD);
            System.out.println(currentTheme.getPrimary());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            currentTheme = createDefaultTheme();
            System.out.println("WARN getThemeFromJSON Exception");
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static Theme createDefaultTheme() {
        Map<String, ChatColor> thisMap = new HashMap<>();

        thisMap.putIfAbsent("primary", ChatColor.GOLD);
        return new Theme(thisMap);
    }

    public static void writeThemeToJSON(Theme thisTheme, File thisFile) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Writer writer = new FileWriter(thisFile, false);
        gson.toJson(thisTheme, writer);
        writer.flush(); writer.close();
    }

    public static Theme getThemeFromJSON(File thisFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Reader reader = new FileReader(thisFile);
        return gson.fromJson(reader, Theme.class);
    }
}
```

**Console output of ThemeManager.load()**

```
[20:20:56 INFO]: §6
[20:20:56 INFO]: Â§6
```

**Example of saved .json file**

```json
{
  "primary": {
    "toString": "§6",
    "name": "gold",
    "ordinal": 6,
    "color": {
      "value": -22016,
      "falpha": 0.0
    }
  }
}
```

**The `Â` comes out of nowhere!**

Comment: Most likely the issue is due to wrong Charset, construct your FileReader with the correct one and it should alleviate the problem.

Comment: @AnthonyCathers how to do that? In the JavaDocs FileReady has no charset argument in the constructor it seems?

Comment: [Since 11 FileReader does have ctors taking charset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileReader.html#constructor.summary); before that or otherwise use `new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream (file), charset)`. Or set the JVM default at startup with `-Dfile.encoding=`. An extra cap-A-hat (C2) before chars that should be A0 or 80 to FF is characteristic of using UTF-8 where 8859 (e.g. Latin-1) or similar like WIndows-1252 is expected.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 your solution works! feel free to add the answer so I can accept it and you can earn the credits :)

(used the InputStreamReader method from your comment)

Answer (score 0):

Solution credit: @dave_thompson_085

The project (and the .json file) are encoded in UTF-8, but I was not reading the file using UTF-8 encoding. Apparently that is not the default encoding of a FileReader object.

By changing this:

```java
public static Theme getThemeFromJSON(File thisFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Reader reader = new FileReader(thisFile);
    return gson.fromJson(reader, Theme.class);
}
```

to this:

```java
public static Theme getThemeFromJSON(File thisFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader (
                new FileInputStream (thisFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return gson.fromJson(reader, Theme.class);
}
```

, the stdout lines from ThemeManager.load() are now both showing `§6` as expected.

However, note that when using `aThemeObject.getPrimary()`, the returned ChatColor object was not able to be used in place of regular calls to `ChatColor.COLOR`.

Trying to do so would simply result in "null" appearing in the displayed text in-game.

To fix this, I modified the get methods to:

```java
public ChatColor getPrimary() {
        return ChatColor.getByChar(primary.toString().charAt(1));
    }
```

char at index 1 is the color code used by the getByChar method to return a clone chatcolor object.

This will prevent using custom falpha values and custom color values in the theme.json file, but ensures the resulting ChatColor object from calling `Theme.getPrimary()` can always be used in place of a regular call to `ChatColor.COLOR`